# reference binding to null pointer of type 'value_type' LeetCode 832

Tags: c++

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<int>> flipAndInvertImage(vector<vector<int>>& A) {
        for(int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++){
            std::reverse(A[i].begin(), A[i].end());
            for(int j = 0; j < A[i].size(); i++ ){
                 if(A[i][j] == 0){
                     A[i][j] = 1;
                 }
                else{
                    A[i][j] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        return A;
    }
};
```

This is for LeetCode problem 832. I can't seem to find what is wrong with my code. I invert the the contents of each vector of integers and then invert the values. Any help please?

Comment: What do you expect this to do?  How is it not doing what you expect?

Comment: You have a typo. The inner loop increment should be `j++` instead of `i++`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo where you increment the wrong index.

You can avoid such problems by using range loops

```
vector<vector<int>> flipAndInvertImage(vector<vector<int>>& a) {
    for (auto& v: a) {
        std::reverse(v.begin(), v.end());
        for (auto& c: v) {
            c = !c;
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

or by avoiding loops

```
vector<vector<int>> flipAndInvertImage(vector<vector<int>>& a)
{
    std::for_each(a.begin(),
                  a.end(),
                  [](vector<int>& b) {
                      std::reverse(b.begin(), b.end());
                      std::transform(b.begin(), b.end(), b.begin(), [](int i) { return !i; })
                  });
    return a;
}
```

(The "modify the argument *and* return a copy" idea is a bit strange. You may want to rethink that.)

Comment: What do you mean by modify the argument and return a copy? The vector is passed by reference so am I not modifying the vector itself rather than a copy? Also since this a function I would have to return something. How would you prefer to do it?

Comment: Ahh are range loops from Professional C++? I cannot understand the syntax you displayed haha. I will definitely look into the syntax for range loops.

Comment: Range loops are in C++11, so it's pretty old by now; compilers have supported it for a decade or so. And you're both modifying the argument itself and returning a copy of it as result. Normally you do one or the other – that is, either you modify the argument and return nothing (`void`) or you leave the argument intact and return the result.

Comment: Oh... so I can reduce the amount of code i write with this-_-. Basically is a two for one function if I am understanding correctly. Thank you for the help, I appreciate it!